# UserControl extending ScrollableControl - disable container functinality

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-controls

I'm building custom control by extending `ScrollableControl`.
Problem is that my custom control acts as container - I can drag controls into it:
[image]

My question is how can I disable container functionality in class that extends `ScrollableControl`

Below are two test controls, one extends `Control`, second `ScrollableControl`

```
public class ControlBasedControl : Control
{
    protected override Size DefaultSize
    {
        get { return new Size(100, 100); }
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.LightCoral, ClientRectangle);
    }
}

public class ScrollableControlBasedControl : ScrollableControl
{
    public ScrollableControlBasedControl()
    {
        AutoScrollMinSize = new Size(200, 200);
    }

    protected override Size DefaultSize
    {
        get { return new Size(100, 100); }
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.LawnGreen, ClientRectangle);
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe, you can try to handle the Drop Event the null the Container property or clear children in the target control.

Comment: @BaranovskiyDmitry I want to disable this as design time. Drop Event will work at runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get "acts-like-a-container" behavior at design time from the [Designer] attribute.  Copy-pasting from the [Reference Source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/ScrollableControl.cs,24feec50034d1f25):

```
[
ComVisible(true),
ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDispatch),
Designer("System.Windows.Forms.Design.ScrollableControlDesigner, " + AssemblyRef.SystemDesign)
]
public class ScrollableControl : Control, IArrangedElement {
   // etc...
}
```

It is ScrollableControlDesigner that gets the job done.  Doesn't do much by itself, but derived from ParentControlDesigner, the designer that permits a control to act as a parent for child controls and gives it container-like behavior at design time.

Fix is easy, you just have to use your own [Designer] attribute to select another designer.  Add a reference to System.Design and make it look like this:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Forms.Design; // Add reference to System.Design

[Designer(typeof(ControlDesigner))]
public class ScrollableControlBasedControl : ScrollableControl {
    // etc...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is probably more than one way to accomplish this, but here is what I would do...

First create a read-only version of [`ControlCollection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
public class ReadOnlyControlCollection : Control.ControlCollection
{
    public ReadOnlyControlCollection(Control owner)
        : base(owner)
    {
    }

    public override bool IsReadOnly
    {
        get { return true; }
    }

    public override void Add(Control control)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("control");
    }
}
```

Then make your `ScrollableControlBasedControl` create an instance of `ReadOnlyControlCollection` in stead of the default [`ControlCollection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
public class ScrollableControlBasedControl : ScrollableControl
{
    protected override Control.ControlCollection CreateControlsInstance()
    {
        return new ReadOnlyControlCollection(this);
    }

    // The rest of your class goes here...
}
```

I use Visual Studio 2010 and when I drop a control on an `ScrollableControlBasedControl` the control is magically moved back to where it came from, as if the action was cancelled.